# Django 1.7.6 BUG with DateTimeField(auto_now=True) AND .update queries?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I encountered a pretty serous bug, that took me a few hours to figure out why I couldn't connect all the dots in Postgres Database.

I have a model in my django app which has this field:

```
last_modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

At one point in my code I use

```
members.update(first_name=first_name,.....)
```

Everything works fine and updates fine EXCEPT one field:

```
last_modified_on
```

After doing some research, I found [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15566), but version and date of that fix are very questionable.

Does anyone know what's up and what's the best way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

> Realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does
>   not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the
>   pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling
>   Model.save()). If you want to update a bunch of records for a model
>   that has a custom save() method, loop over them and call save(), like
>   this:

```
for m in YourModel.objects.filter(....):
    m.first_name = "First Name"
    m.save()
```

You should also know that if you have a customer `save` method inside you model it will not be called. be in the safe area.